# iOS obtaining touch type in HitTest method

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to check touch is made by stylus in HitTest method. If touch is made by stylus I want to return default HitTest result, otherwise I want to return nil.

The problem is I cannot obtain touch type from uiEvent. How can I check the touch type?

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: But there is no code to post. Every iOS view rendered got HitTest method. And what I want is to check if touch is made by Apple pencil or not in this method.